# Querying dynamodb with begins_with

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How do I query a dynamodb with both dataset_id and an image_name. Using the code below:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name') 
response = table.query(
           IndexName='dataset_id',
           KeyConditionExpression='dataset_id = :value AND begins_with (image_name, :name)',
           ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':value': str(dataset_id),
              ':name': {'S', 'a'}
           },
           Limit=int(results_per_page)
```

This is my dynamodb GSIs.

[dymamodb GSIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GxFY.png)

What I'm I doing wrong here?

I am expecting the dynamodb response to return images that start with 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I assume your GSI is called `dataset_id` and its partition key is `dataset_id` and its sort key is `image_name`, if this assumption is false then your use-case is not valid.

Now to the issue I see, you are using `Resource` client which uses native JSON not DDB-JSON, so your query should look like this:

```
response = table.query(
           IndexName='dataset_id',
           KeyConditionExpression='dataset_id = :value AND begins_with (image_name, :name)',
           ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':value': str(dataset_id),
              ':name': 'a'
           },
           Limit=int(results_per_page))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lee, image_name is actually the partition key for the second GSI. Does that not make sense? I want to query on a certain dataset_id and then on a specific prefix based on image_name.

Comment: For that use case `dataset_id` needs to be the partition key with `image_name` being the sort key. This allows you to search for a given dataset_id with a condition on image_name.

Comment: I'll try that out today and put my outcomes here. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, as I still get this error:
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported`

I have made the image index to be a sort key

Comment: Can you share the code you're trying along with the output of a `describe_table` call. You can add the contents to your question the comment here and I'll review.

Comment: what if you try these separately?     items = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('image_name').begins_with('a')
    ) note that the 'a' may be just a without quotes. i've had luck with this notation.

  
    items = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('dataset_id').eq('youridvaluehere')
    )  if you get each condition to work, then maybe figure out the 'AND' part of it

Comment: @LeeHannigan my apologies I was wrong it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.